# "Two months before Halloween" or "to Halloween" or "until Halloween"

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the preposition you can use before the day for a celebration.

If you see a friend buying Halloween-themed decorations today and you think it might be too early, which sentence can you say?

> We have more than two months **before** Halloween.
>
> We have more than two months **to** Halloween.
>
> We have more than two months **until** Halloween.

I don't know which preposition to use before "Halloween" in this sentence.

Comment: You could use any one of those.

Comment: Sentence 2 seems better suited to "There are..." than to "We have..."